# Compositional inverse of Bessel function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions

Was ever studied a function $f$ which solves $J_0(f(x))=x$? Integral representations, natural domains of existence and whatever.

Comment: For the record: the differential equation is given [here](https://doi.org/10.1002/sapm1957361167), but apparently not much more is said about $J_0^{-1}$ there.

Answer (score 3):

Function $J_0$ belongs to the so-called Laguerre-Polya class. The "natural domain" of the inverse function of an entire function of this class is a simply connected Riemann surface whose structure has been described by
Gerald MacLane in the paper  Concerning the uniformization of certain Riemann surfaces
allied to the inverse-cosine and inverse-gamma surfaces, Trans. Amer.
Math. Soc. 62 (1947) 99–113.

For a modern exposition, of this work, you may consult
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1464.